# F# Query Expression / select operator / changing column headings in result

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

In the following code:

```
#r "System.Data.dll"
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"
#r "System.Data.Linq.dll"

open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
open System.Windows.Forms

type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"...">


let grid<'T> (x:seq<'T>) =...

let query1 =
    query {
        for row in db.Status do
        //select row
        select (row.StatusID, row.Name)
    }


query1 |> Seq.toArray |> grid
```

[image]

What are the better ways to change columns to meaningful headings (e.g. actual Column from data source) instead of of just (Item1 Item2...).

Note: For grid function, please [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000305/function-to-visualizing-data-in-a-grid-in-f) Tomas Petricek response.

Regards,
IP

Answer (score 6):

You can select the data as a record to let `DataGridView` infer the names of the columns

```
type Status =
    {
        StatusID: int
        Name: string
    }

let query1 =
    query {
        for row in db.Status do
        select { StatusID = row.StatusID; Name = row.Name }
    }
```

Comment: I think he's interested in a way to get the names automatically from the source.

Comment: Yes that is correct. However, as requested this could be one of the alternatives. Thank you to both. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This should a bit nicer now in F# 4.6 using the new [Anonymous Record](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/207) feature.

```
let query1 =
    query {
        for row in db.Status do
        //select row
        select {| StatusID = row.StatusID; Name = row.Name; |}
    }
```

Notice the use of the | character on the insides of the curly braces. This is what now distinguishes regular records from anonymous records in F#. Also notice that the property names `StatusID` and `Name` must be redundantly specified in the current form. Although this is similar to how constructing objects works in JavaScript, .NET Developers have been enjoying a more abbreviated syntax through C# anonymous types. The feature to allow for similar [implicit property names](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/734) is suggested as a followup change in future language specifications.